# Setting image upload path

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to add an image upload script to my site and I do not think I have it configured correctly to go to my directories.

The directory I am trying to upload to: `images/gallery/`

The directory my code is in: `scripts/php/imageUpload.php`

And the php code in `imageUpload.php`:

```
<?php
$output_dir = "../images/gallery/";

if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
    $ret = array();

    $error =$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
   {

        if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]['name'])) //single file
        {
            $RandomNum   = time();

            $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['myfile']['name']));
            $ImageType      = $_FILES['myfile']['type']; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.

            $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
            $ImageExt       = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
            $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
            $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir. $NewImageName);
             //echo "<br> Error: ".$_FILES["myfile"]["error"];

                 $ret[$fileName]= $output_dir.$NewImageName;
        }
        else
        {
            $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]['name']);
            for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
            {
                $RandomNum   = time();

                $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i]));
                $ImageType      = $_FILES['myfile']['type'][$i]; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.

                $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
                $ImageExt       = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
                $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
                $NewImageName = $ImageName.'-'.$RandomNum.'.'.$ImageExt;

                $ret[$NewImageName]= $output_dir.$NewImageName;
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$NewImageName );
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($ret);

}

?>
```

I have tried changing the directory from `../images/gallery/` to  `/images/gallery/` and to `images/gallery/`

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Do you have any kind of `config.php` file that defines a root?

Comment: You mean like a php.ini file? I don't know what you mean honestly. First time working with uploads.

Comment: No, I mean like a file that maybe includes some key settings. It would be a file that gets included on all your pages. Usually included first.

Comment: Yes I do. I think I have 2 or 3 actually.

Comment: Is one of those files in your root folder?

Comment: No, but I can easily add one if needed.

Comment: Usually, if you put a config.php file in your root folder that has something like: `define("ROOTDIR",getcwd());` (or similar), now you have a constant that has a solid root that you can include with your other includes like so: `$dir = ROOTDIR.'/my/super/file.php';`

Comment: So my problem lies with not directing to my document root? What if I try to add $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] to my codes directory in the above?

Comment: Well, you can have relative paths, I personally find it easier to include files based on the root. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` works in general. I have heard that setting may not be 100% reliable, but I have found it works well.

Comment: Well I did change the directory line to $output_dir = "/home/jollyrogerpcs/public_html/images/gallery/"; which is my directory root and that didn't work either.

Comment: Is that generated from the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or did you manually write that?

Comment: Generated by echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in my index.php file

Comment: Also, have you confirmed it has successfully uploaded to somewhere? I would try making a part in your code that creates the folder before dropping in the file just to see if it uploads at all. Use `mkdir("directory/path",true);` to do that.

Comment: I'm actually using a pre-written code from: http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-upload-multiple-images-jquery-ajax-using-php_453.html so i'm not sure how to write that into their honestly. It's all a learning process.

Comment: To create a folder in your scenario, you would add this line before you do the `move_upload_files` part. `if(!is_dir($output_dir)) mkdir($output_dir,true);` after, refresh your server and see if that folder is made...somewhere. I would prepend the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to it though

Comment: Added it and no new directory was created.

Comment: Sorry, I gave you an inaccurate mkdir. Should be: `mkdir($output_dir,0755,true);` it needs the permissions.

Comment: Still no change. I ran my code through a syntax checker and it had no errors so I'm thinking maybe it's a permission issue with uploading? I do have file uploads turned on in my php.ini file though.

Comment: Post the form you are using to upload.

Comment: The form is javascript generated. I only make a regular div and the js replaces it with what is needed.

Comment: Ah...well if you are doing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form and you have named the file input `myfile` then the form shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what I did but it started working lol At this point I'm confused, but hopefully I will catch on so I can post the solution for anyone else with a similar issue. Thanks for bearing with me.

Answer (score 0):

if you use wamp on windows operating system try this

```
$output_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "images/gallery/";
```

else try this

```
$output_dir = dirname(__FILE__)."/../images/gallery/";
```

Comment: try second variable
$output_dir = dirname(__FILE__)."/../images/gallery/";

Comment: `$output_dir = dirname(__FILE__)."/../../images/gallery/";` try this because you have two parents